# Show Google Customer Review only after click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Googles Customer Reviews. It works fine. But my goal is, that the autooverlay is only loaded after I click on a button with id="google-review"

The original Code is:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>
<script>
        window.renderOptIn = function() {
            window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
                window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                    {
                        "merchant_id": number,
                        "order_id": order_id,
                        "email": customer_email,
                        "delivery_country": delivery_country,
                        "estimated_delivery_date": estimated_delivery_date,
                        "opt_in_style": "BOTTOM_TRAY"
                    });
            });
        }
</script>
```

I tried:

```
    $("#google-review").click(function() {
    window.renderOptIn = function () {
        window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function () {
            window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                {
                    "merchant_id": number,
                    "order_id": order_id,
                    "email": customer_email,
                    "delivery_country": delivery_country,
                    "estimated_delivery_date": estimated_delivery_date,
                    "opt_in_style": "BOTTOM_TRAY"
                });
        });
    }
});
```

But this is not working. The overlay is not loading at all. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: I suspect the onload parameter in the script src is a callback function name needed in global/window scope: `window.renderOptIn`. Wrapping it inside a click handler puts it inside it own scope. Open your browser console and you might see an error saying that renderOptIn is not defined.

Comment: I dont see anything in the console. No error at all :S

Comment: it may be that google's script checks for existence of that function, so try my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the other way around. Script source onload calls `renderOptin`. This then sets up a click handler. Actual click executes the code inside the function:

```
window.renderOptIn = function() {
  $("#google-review").click(function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
      window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
        "merchant_id": number,
        "order_id": order_id,
        "email": customer_email,
        "delivery_country": delivery_country,
        "estimated_delivery_date": estimated_delivery_date,
        "opt_in_style": "BOTTOM_TRAY"
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you alot! I tried so many dirty solutions, but this one works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution just avoids the parameter 'onload' when you load js like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
$("#google-review").click(function() {
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function () {
        window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
                "merchant_id": number,
                "order_id": order_id,
                "email": customer_email,
                "delivery_country": delivery_country,
                "estimated_delivery_date": estimated_delivery_date,
                "opt_in_style": "BOTTOM_TRAY"
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this is works, especially combine with PHP

```
$('.send-trigger').on('click',function(){

            var orderId = $(this).attr('order-id');
            var custEmail = $(this).attr('customer-email');

            window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
                window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                {

                "merchant_id": 1234534535345354,
                "order_id": orderId,
                "email": custEmail,
                "delivery_country": "XX",
                "estimated_delivery_date": "<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>"
                });
            });

});
```